# Cargo pants with military colors

Tags: international-travel, dress-codes

I am looking trousers for travelling and [cargo trousers](https://www.flipkart.com/xee-men-s-cargos/p/itmf8wxnn5asmwgz?pid=CRGF8WUYUTKATNBR&lid=LSTCRGF8WUYUTKATNBRRNKVPZ&marketplace=FLIPKART&srno=b_1_5&otracker=browse&fm=organic&iid=8b934859-c2fc-455a-ae66-d47a70875d1f.CRGF8WUYUTKATNBR.SEARCH&ppt=SearchPage&ppn=Search) seem to be good option.

Many of these trousers are in military colours which is making me a bit reluctant. Anybody is aware of countries where such trousers can lead to issues?

Comment: You can get grey cargo pants. Grey trousers are worn the world over.

Comment: People are voting to close as too broad but I think the answer makes it clear that this is perfectly, well, answerable.

Comment: @WeatherVane also dark blue (police sometimes wear these), khaki, tan, brown, black, and probably more.  But maybe these are considered "military colors" here.  Travelling Juggernaut: what do you mean by "military colors" here?

Answer (score 8):

Wikipedia has a handy list: [List of nations that prohibit camouflage clothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nations_that_prohibit_camouflage_clothing). It lists 11 countries, including major destinations in the Caribbean, some countries in the Middle East and Africa, and the Philippines.

You'd need to research the exact laws to know whether the trousers in question are prohibited, but yes, there are countries where wearing camouflage can cause issues. The same style in neutral tones would be more universally acceptable.

Comment: There are also countries which prohibit the wearing of military uniforms one is not entitled to wear, but just the trousers are usually not considered uniform.